# Don't show in preview but show in print layout

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

I have simple query and the SSRS result is empty in the Preview page but all the correct result is shows in the print layout.
The data source and dataset is very simple soo i think the problem is not there.

Preview:

[image]

Printing Layout:

[image]

Comment: Is your design tool up to date? Is this happening on other reports or just this one?

Comment: Do you see a `.data` file in your project folder? If you see, delete it and retry. Preview does not work a lot of the times for me because of the cache.

Comment: My design tool is up to date and this happens with all reports what i create. The existing items are working great. 
I tried to delete the **.data** file.